# Effect of NOT changing filter weights of CNN during backprop

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, mnist

What is the effect of NOT changing filter weights of a CNN during backpropagation? I changed only the fully connected layer weights while training on the MNIST dataset and still achieved almost 99 percent accuracy.

Comment: Interesting, did you start with random weights, or using weights from some previous network? Also is your accuracy measure from the training set, or from a hold out test set?

Comment: @Neil Slater : I started with random gaussian weights .The accuracy measure is on test set.

Comment: @Neil Slater: The accuracy almost remains the same even with different initializations of the filters. I used 2 convolution and max pool layers and an FC layer with 256 hidden neurons

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By not changing the weights of the convolutional layers of a CNN, you are essentially feeding your classifier (the fully connected layer) **random features** (i.e. **not the optimal** features for the classification task at hand).

MNIST is an **easy** enough image classification task that you can pretty much feed the input pixels to a classifier without any feature extraction and it will still score in the high 90s. Besides that, perhaps the pooling layers help a bit...

Try training an MLP (without the conv/pool layers) on the input image and see how it ranks. [Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/) is an example where an MLP (1 hidden & 1 output layer) reached 98+% without any preprocessing/feature extraction.

---

Edit:

I'd also like to point out to [another answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/426878/119015) I wrote, which goes into more detail on *why* MNIST is so easy as an image classification task.